# jQuery Ajax function does not respond when Node server crushes

Tags: node.js, jquery

I have a problem with a jQuery Ajax request that does not respond when my NodeJS server crushes.

```
function postRequest(url, query, onComplete) {

    $.post(url, query)

    .done(function (response) {
        onComplete(false, response);
    })

    .fail(function (xhr) {
        onComplete(true, xhr.status);
    }); 
}

postRequest('/noderoute', {id: 4}, function (error, res) {
    if (!error) {
        $('#content').html(res);
    }
    else {
        alert(res);
    }
});
```

If the server responds, all is good and well but if it crushes nothing happens. How can I solve this? Thank you.

**Edit: Solved**

I have been running my tests on a production build instead of my development files. Everything working fine now.

Comment: what do you mean by "crushes"? as in if the node process stops entirely?

Comment: @compid - yes that's what I mean.

Comment: could you use the chrome inspector or some debugging tool to see the details of the network request, e.g. what was sent and returned?

Comment: It returns 503 Service Unavailable

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an incorrect `xhr` argument to your `fail` call.

```
.fail(xhr, function () {
```

should be

```
.fail(function (xhr) {
```

Comment: Sorry, its a typo - had to re-write it for clarity. Doesn't work still.